# itext table with fixed cell width and centered text

Tags: java, itext

I want to create a table with fixed width and centered aligned text. But the table I am creating does not get centered "X" for each cell. Its still left aligned. Why?

```
       Table table = new Table(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            Cell cell = new Cell();
            cell.setWidth(30);
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
            Paragraph p = new Paragraph("X");
            p.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
            cell.add(p);
            table.addCell(cell);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself, gotta use emptyCell.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
and not setHorizontalAlignment. However, for vertical alignment, setVerticalAlignment is used.